# WPF - Print contents of ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, printing

I've created my own usercontrol that makes use of a ListView to display an arbitratry list of items.  On each Page within my project the ListView's columns in XAML and then bound to my object.

Now what I'm trying to do is to write a single Print method within my control that will print out the entire contents of the ListView.

I read a similar question where the answer was stated that I should convert my ItemsSource into a Table.  If, indeed, that is the way to accomplish this task, can someone be so kind as to walk me through that process for an arbitrary object?

Thanks,
Sonny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I finally (sort of) solved the issue.

I've iterated through the GridViewColumns within my ListView and for each column I also iterate through the ItemSource of the ListView and use Reflection to get the DisplayMemberBinding.Path.Path which I can then use to get the property's value.

The DisplayMemberBinding also has information for all my converters, so I'm good to go.

It's slow (about 10 seconds for 400 lines in a ListView), but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx) derives from [Visual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx), maybe you can use the [PrintVisual()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual.aspx) method to print the list view itself:

```
new PrintDialog().PrintVisual(yourListView, "Print Job Description");
```

Comment: That was my first instinct as well. Unfortunately, for some of my ListViews containing larger numbers of items, it wants to show the scrollbar instead of all the items.  Do you know a way around that?

Comment: @Sonny, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205112/printing-a-collection-in-wpf) speaks of the same problem. The accepted answer uses a `FlowDocument` to hold the list view items.

Comment: @Fréd - How would I do this for an arbitrarty object?  I'm unsure of how to get the collection of rows and columns out of a ListView so that I can iterate through them...

Comment: @Sonny, you could enumerate your `ItemsSource` directly. It's an `IEnumerable`, so `foreach` loops and LINQ queries will work on it.

Comment: @Fréd - But then I wouldn't I have to write a special case for every type of object displayed in my ListView?  I use a number of Converters and Templates to get my objects displaying in the ListView.  By iterating through the ItemsSource, I work directly with the objects and bypass all the formatting I'm trying to preserve during the printing process.

Comment: @Sonny, good point. Since you have to go through the `ListView` but force it to display its whole contents somehow, I don't know of any solution... Maybe someone else will :)